# C++ template how to overloading operator and accessing private property

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword, friend

I am currently trying to implement a simple template-based linked list that takes a generic key/value-pair in C++11. Elements should be added to the list by the += operator. The code looks like this:

**list**

```
// Forward declarations
template<typename K, typename V>
class list;

template<typename K, typename V>
list<K, V> &operator+=(list<K, V> &list, const std::tuple<K, V> ele) {
    if (!list.head) {
        // list is empty
        list.head = new element(ele, nullptr);
    }

    return list;
};

// Class definition
template<typename K, typename V>
class list {
private:
    struct element {
        const K key;
        const V value;
        element *next;

        element(const std::tuple<K, V> tuple, element *ele) :
                key(std::get<0>(tuple)),
                value(std::get<1>(tuple)),
                next(ele) { }
    };

    element *head = nullptr;

public:
    friend list<K, V> &operator+=<>(list<K, V> &list, const std::tuple<K, V> ele);
};
```

I can't get this to compile. Do I have to put the implementation of the operator into the forward declaration or into the class itself? If I put it in the forward-declaration, like in the snippet, I can't seem to use "list.head = new element(ele, nullptr);". Error: expected type-specifier before ‘element’

If I put it into the class itself, I can't access list.head even tho it's a friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just leave the declaration of the function template before the class template definition (after the forward declaration), to tell the compiler that `operator+=` specified in the friend declaration is a template. Then define it later. e.g.

```
// Forward declarations
template<typename K, typename V>
class list;

// declaration of function template
template<typename K, typename V>
list<K, V> &operator+=(list<K, V> &l, const std::tuple<K, V> ele);

// Class definition
template<typename K, typename V>
class list {
    ...
    friend list<K, V> &operator+=<>(list<K, V> &l, const std::tuple<K, V> ele);
};

// definition of function template
template<typename K, typename V>
list<K, V> &operator+=(list<K, V> &l, const std::tuple<K, V> ele) {
    if (!l.head) {
        // list is empty
        l.head = new typename list<K, V>::element(ele, nullptr);
    }

    return l;
}
```

PS:

1. Don't name the parameter with the name `list`, which conflicts with the name of class template `list`.
2. `element` is a nested struct, in `operator+=` you should specify it like `typename list<K, V>::element`.
3. Using name `list` (same as `std::list`) is not a good idea.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F7NDRdDjhqHVffFw)

Comment: Thanks, this helps. But why do I need a forward declaration AND a declaration in the class?

Comment: @octavio To tell the compiler that `operator+=` specified in the friend declaration is a template.